# How to find specific key in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I have to find all the documents which include "p396:branchCode" as key in MongoDB.Value does not matter,can be anything.I tried using

```
{"p396:branchCode": new RegExp(".*")}
```

in MongoVUE but i found nothing.
My db is very nested and branchCode has superkey "p396:checkTellersEApproveStatus"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is nested under a super-key, so you need to use the dot-operator:

```
{"p396:checkTellersEApproveStatus.p396:branchCode": {$exists: true}}
```

This assumes `p396:branchCode` is always under `p396:checkTellersEApproveStatus`. When that's not the case, you have a problem, because MongoDB does not allow to do queries for unknown keys. When the number of possible super-keys is low, you could query for all of them with the $or-operator. When not, then your only option is to refactor your objects to arrays. To give an example, a structure like this:

```
properties: {
     prop1: "value1",
     prop2: "value2",
     prop3: "value3"
}
```

would be far easier to query for values under arbitrary keys when made to look like this:

```
properties: [
     { key: "prop1", value:"value1"} ,
     { key: "prop2", value:"value2"},
     { key: "prop3", value:"value3"}
]
```

because you could just do `db.collection.find({"properties.value":"value2"})`

Comment: Number of possible super-keys is not low in my case,it big data project so it is very very big.It is very sad MongoDB has no feature like this

Comment: @BerkKarabacak When your tool is not the right for the job, don't blame the tool. Blame the one who picked it... or learn to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator.

```
{'p396:branchCode': {$exists: true}}
```

This assumes this query is part of the path:

```
{ 'p396:checkTellersApproveStatus': {'p396:branchCode': {$exists: true}}}
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
{ 'p396:checkTellersApproveStatus.p396:branchCode': {$exists: true}}
```

Comment: You forgot to consider the heavy nesting of the DB. That is the main problem here.

Comment: @Philipp Not really. I only modified the part of the query the OP provided. But to make it explicit I have included the path as far as I can tell from the provided screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually "mixing types then that probably is not a good thing. But if all you care about is that the field [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) then that is the operator to use:

```js
db.collection.find({ 
   "p396:checkTellersApproveStatus.p396:branchCode": { "$exists": true }
})
```

If the values are actuall "all" numeric and you have an expected "range" then use [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators instead. This allows an "index" on the field to be used. And a "sparse" index where this was not present in all documents would improve performance:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "p396:checkTellersApproveStatus.p396:branchCode": {
        "$gt": 0, "$lt": 99999
    }
})
```

In all cases, this is the "child" of the parent "p396:checkTellersApproveStatus", so you use "not notation" to acess the full path to the property.